Deploying GraphQL backend to vercel
GraphQL Server Works Locally but Fails in Production on Vercel
I've developed a web app using GraphQL as the backend API service. The code works perfectly in local development, but when I try to make it production-ready on Vercel, I encounter issues. Here are the details:
Local Development Code (server.js)
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "apollo-server-core";
import typeDefs from './logic/schemaGQL.js';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
const MONGO_URI = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const SECRATE = process.env.SECRATE;

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("connected to mongodb")
})

mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("error connecting", err)
})

import './DB/User.js'
import './DB/SubWaiting.js'
import './DB/Sub.js'
import './DB/Msg.js'
import './DB/SubUncheck.js'
import './DB/Revenue.js'
import './DB/Month.js'
import './DB/PlanSold.js'
import './DB/Waiting.js'
import './DB/Refund.js'
import './DB/Help.js'

import resolvers from './logic/resolver.js'

const context = ({ req }) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
    if (authorization) {
        const { userId } = jwt.verify(authorization, SECRATE)
        return { userId }
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context,
    plugins: [
        ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()
    ]
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});

Production Code for Vercel (server.js)

import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from 'apollo-server-core';
import typeDefs from './logic/schemaGQL.js';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const MONGO_URI = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const SECRATE = process.env.SECRATE;

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
    // console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
    // console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB", err);
});

import resolvers from './logic/resolver.js';

const context = ({ req }) => {
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
    if (authorization) {
        const { userId } = jwt.verify(authorization, SECRATE);
        return { userId };
    }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context,
    plugins: [
        ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
    ],
});


// const startServer = server.start();


export default server.createHandler({
    path: '/api/graphql',
});

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

vercel.json Configuration
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{
        "src": "server.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
    }],
    "routes": [{
        "src": "/api/graphql",
        "dest": "/api/graphql"
    }]
}

I also tried changing the routes in vercel.json to:
"routes": [{
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "/api"
}]

The Issue
When I try to hit this URL: https://splits-two.vercel.app/api/graphql, I sometimes get 404 Not Found, 500 Internal Server Error, or a serverless error indicating a crash.
The app works perfectly fine locally. What could be causing these issues in production on Vercel?

You appear to be using apollo-server v2 [which reached EOL (end of life) 10/2023] or v3 [EOL 10/2024]. Instead, you should be using Apollo v4. @apollo/server is the replacement for apollo-server, and @as-integrations/next is the replacement for apollo-server-micro.
See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@as-integrations/next
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';

import resolvers from './logic/resolver.js'
import typeDefs from './logic/schemaGQL.js';

const server = new ApolloServer({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
});

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server, {
  context,
});

Once you've got that in place, what errors are you getting from your server?
